# Trying to add an ampersand at the end of every line of file using sed

Tags: command-line, sed

I am trying to add an ampersand at the end of every line of a file using `sed` as follows:

`sed -i -e 's/$/ &/' file`

However, when I look at the contents of the file (using both Vim and just `cat`ing the file) I don't see the ampersand (only an extra space). I tried with another character 'l' and it worked. Why doesn't it work with ampersand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&` is one of very few characters that is special on the replacement side of a sed `s/pattern/replacement/` command - in particular, it is replaced by the whole matched portion of the pattern space. In this case, the whole matched portion is a zero length assertion `$`, so `&` appears to insert nothing in the replacement.

To add a literal ampersand, you therefore need to escape it:

```
sed -i -e 's/$/ \&/' file
```